# Writing to database (Vaadin Flow)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, vaadin, rapidclipse

I bound several text fields to an entity in the IDE Rapidclipse that uses Vaadin 14 and JPA/Hibernate. The aim is to write the input data on button click into the referring database that is defined as datasource.
I already found this documentation
[Writing manually](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-components-binder-load.html#validating-and-writing-manually).
So my understanding of this is like that: At first i need to create a new bean of the entity (`Test test = new Test()`). Then all input data should be assigned to the attributes of the bean(`binder.writeBean(test)`). That's as far as the documentation goes. But how does the data get inserted into the table of the entity in my database? Do i need the TestDAO class?

In Vaadin 7, which was used in the former Rapidclipse version, it worked like this:

```
fieldGroup.setItemDatasource(new Test());
...
fieldgroup.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

`Binder` is used to bind attributes of a `Bean` to a form(TextFields, for example) displayed in UI. So when you are doing something like this [How to Bind Form Data](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-components-binder.html#how-to-bind-form-data)

```
Binder<Person> binder = new Binder<>(Person.class);

TextField titleField = new TextField();

// Start by defining the Field instance to use
binder.forField(titleField)
        // Finalize by doing the actual binding
        // to the Person class
        .bind(
                // Callback that loads the title
                // from a person instance
                Person::getTitle,
                // Callback that saves the title
                // in a person instance
                Person::setTitle);
```

you are exactly stating that `titleField` displays a title of a person. `Binder` is **not related to/responsible of** a DB persistence. 
In the documentation you linked, in all examples there is a row similar to this:
`MyBackend.updatePersonInDatabase(person);`. It's a responsibility of a developer to persist object into underlying database. Flow is a UI framework and that is the reason you are free to choose a database provider/technology.

Regarding Vaadin 7, where you have found an example? I can't find a method `save` on a `FieldGroup` class [FieldGroup API](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/7.7.17/com/vaadin/data/fieldgroup/FieldGroup.html)

Maybe someone has extended it and added a needed functionality?

So, for example, if you are using hibernate something along the line of this:

`session.save(emp);` will insert your object into DB.
Taken from here: [Hibernate Insert Query Tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-insert-query-tutorial/)

Some other useful links:

- [Hibernate: save, persist, update, merge, saveOrUpdate](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate)
- [Implementing the Repository pattern with JPA and Hibernate](https://thoughts-on-java.org/implementing-the-repository-pattern-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)
- [What is the difference between Hibernate and Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23862994/what-is-the-difference-between-hibernate-and-spring-data-jpa/23863416#23863416)
- [Data Transfer Object](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)

Comment: So nothing has change in this sense between Vaadin 7 and Vaadin 14. You can use the same logic as before. `save(entity)` method still takes a object it needs to persist. In your case it's the one written to binder

Comment: And regarding `DAO`. It's up to you, how you would like to implement persistense. `DAO` adds level of abstraction. [Data access object (DAO) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154202/data-access-object-dao-in-java)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. It's pretty obvious. I don't know why i did not get it.

Comment: No problem! Great that it works now and we all have been there trying to narrow down some problem :)