# Query relational database with Spring Data JPA and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am new to Spring and Hibernate. I have a project using Spring, Hibernate and PostgreSQL. I know that I can query the database using Spring Data JPA or Hibernate, but I don't know what the benefits and disadvantages of each approach. I also know that in the background, Spring Data JPA will call Hibernate. So what is the best way I should use to query the database to get the best performance, Spring Data JPA or Hibernate or depending on the specific usage situation. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I think it is based on the requirements of your project.
You can find more answers to this question at [StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23862994/what-is-the-difference-between-hibernate-and-spring-data-jpa/23863416#23863416)