# Object/Entity lifecycles when using spring-data-jpa with hibernate as jpa provider?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When using spring-data-jpa with hibernate as jpa provider, are the Object/Entity lifecycles same as when using hibernate directly or as defined by hibernate (or might be jpa spec itself).

Hibernate defines these lifecycles to entities - `Transient, Persistent, Detached, Removed`.
Are these same life cycles applicable when using spring-data-jpa too.
If so how does below the methods provided by Hibernate map with the methods of spring jpa crud repository.

```
//below methods in hibernate move an entity to persistent state
save(e), 
persist(e);  
update(e);  
saveOrUpdate(e);  
lock(e);  
merge(e);
```

and

```
//below methods in hibernate move an entity to detached state
detach(e);  
evict(e);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first part of the question:

Spring Data JPA just offers some comfortable mechanics on top of JPA.
The persistence, mapping and life cycle is still managed by JPA or its implementation, i.e. Hibernate in your case.
This means the life cycle is the same.

As for the mapping between Spring Data JPAs methods and Hibernates/JPA methods see the following table.

| Spring Data | JPA |
| --- | --- |
| `CrudRepository.save*` | for new entities `EntityManager.persist`, `EntityManager.merge` otherwise |
| `CrudRepository.delete*` | `EntityManager.remove` |
| `CrudRepository.findById` | `EntityManager.find*` |
| `JpaRepository.*flush` | `EntityManager.flush` |
| `JpaRepository.getById` | `EntityManager.getReference` |

Other query methods predefined in interfaces or otherwise use various types of queries.

Comment: good mapping of spring data jpa to jpa. +1. if you like the Q can you upvote it so it helps others too.

Answer (score 2):

**Spring Data Jpa is only an abstraction layer** and not provide a lifecycle management. Therefore, if you are using hibernate as a jpa implementation **your object's lifecycle will regulated according to hibernate's lifecycle management**.

Also, you can find some other explanations [here](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-the-difference-between-hibernate-and-sprin-1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23862994/what-is-the-difference-between-hibernate-and-spring-data-jpa) as well.

Comment: great reference +1. thanks for help. if you got time - would you mind helping with this [Criteria API and JPQL API with GROUP BY and CONCAT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73129333/criteria-api-and-jpql-api-with-group-by-and-concat/73163002#73163002)